# Discrepancy between elements retrieved via e.target and those shown in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, handlebars.js

I'm building a todo list with nested lists. List items are attached to their respective unordered lists with the use of Handlebars templating. The list items each contain a text input to represent them in the browser, empty `<ul></ul>` tags for any future child list items, and a button to add those list items. This works, and the text inputs appear properly in the DOM. However, when I attempt to retrieve newly added `<li></li>` elements via `e.target` beyond the master list, nothing is detected in the child lists, despite the fact that they all appear in the DOM.

In the code, I have an event handler bound to the button which adds a new list item for each list. In this case, e.target is the button. My aim is to use jQuery's `.focus()` on the new item's input so the cursor is already there when it appears. I have tested out using both jQuery and vanilla JS methods in `console.log()` to traverse the tree, going through the button's sibling-level `<ul></ul>` but this does not appear to be a problem with traversal methods, as the lists are always logged, though empty.

In this scenario, one item is present on the master list. Subsequently, one item is added to the first sublist via the event handler function for the "new list item" button (which itself is inside the first item's `<li></li>` tags). Inside that function, I traverse the tree to access the list item's child unordered list and log the result to the console, as with the following:

`console.log(e.target.closest('li').querySelector('ul'));`

The returned result shows that the list is empty:

```
<ul id="list-2" class="parent-list">
        </ul>
```

However, the newly appended list item is clearly visible in the DOM:

```
<ul id="list-2" class="parent-list">
   <li data-id="...">...</li>
 </ul>
```

The relevant HTML including script for list templating with handlebars:

```
<body>
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="toggle-all-checkbox">Toggle All</label>
    <br>
    <button class="add-parent-list-todo">+</button>
    <br>
    <ul id="list-1" class="parent-list">
    </ul>
</body>
<script id="todo-list-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#this}}
    <li {{#if completed}} class="completed" {{/if}} data-id="{{id}}">
        <input class="todo-input" type="text" value="{{text}}">
        <div id='options'>
            <button class="delete">x</button>
            <input type="checkbox">
        </div>
        <br>
        <button class="add-parent-list-todo">+</button>
        <br>
        <ul id="{{childList}}" class="parent-list">
        </ul>
    </li>
    {{/this}}
</script>
```

The event handler function in question:

```
        enterTodoText: function (e) {
            var parentList = $(e.target).next().next().attr('id');

            this.todos.push({
                text: '',
                id: util.uuid(),
                completed: false,
                parentList: parentList,
                childList: "list-" + childListId
            });

            childListId++;
            this.render();
            $(e.target).next().next().children('li:last-child').find('.todo-input').focus();
            console.log(e.target.closest('li').querySelector('ul'))
        }
```

I'd very much appreciate any insight anyone might have.

Comment: Can you please add a snippet containing the relevant code to show a working example of the problem.

Comment: Done. I hope this might be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I have come to realize that this in overwhelming likeliness has something to do with `e.target` being inside of a Handlebars template. Using `e.target` from a template, I am seemingly unable to traverse beyond the template itself. This is confirmed by testing with `console.log($(e.target).parents())`, which shows that for sublists, the topmost detectable parent is `<li>` (which is the parent element in the template), when I expected it to be `<html>`.

The solution I came to is to just traverse the tree using `$('body')` as the starting point, as opposed to `$('e.target')`.